# python pandas: sorting hierarchical headers and adding columns as part of the hierarchical header

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the below data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(11 * 8).reshape((11, 8))

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [
        ('A', 'C1', 'D1'),
        ('A', 'C1', 'D2'),
        ('A', 'C2', 'D3'),
        ('A', 'C2', 'D4'),
        
        ('B', 'C3', 'D5'),
        ('B', 'C3', 'D6'),
        ('B', 'C4', 'D7'),
        ('B', 'C4', 'D8'),
    ],
    names=('a', 'b', 'c',)
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=midx)

df
```

as

```
a   A                B
b   C1      C2      C3      C4
c   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
2   16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
3   24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
4   32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
5   40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
6   48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
7   56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
8   64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
9   72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
10  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
```

Few questions I have:

1. How may I access and sort column D2 in descending order and
   afterwhich add a column (left of column 'A') of running serial number down (1,2,3,4,5
   etc)
2. create a column under C2, so it becomes 'D3' 'D4' 'Delta', where 'Delta' calculates the difference of (D4 - D3) then likewise add another column of running serial number down based on the differences in descending order.

Thank you

Comment: you may print to see how pandas label multiindex columns by `print(df.columns)`. Then pick label of the column which you wanna sort or access, and do those as if it's a single-index column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers in the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
data = np.arange(11 * 8).reshape((11, 8))
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'C1', 'D1'), ('A', 'C1', 'D2'), ('A', 'C2', 'D3'), ('A', 'C2', 'D4'), ('B', 'C3', 'D5'), ('B', 'C3', 'D6'), ('B', 'C4', 'D7'), ('B', 'C4', 'D8')], names=('a', 'b', 'c',))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=midx)

# Q1
df1 = df.copy()

# Access D2
df1.loc[:,('A', 'C1', 'D2')]

# Sort D2 in desc order
df1 = df1.sort_values(('A', 'C1', 'D2'), ascending=False)

# Add serial numbers to only the top level
df1.insert(0, 'serial_num', np.arange(len(df1)) + 1)

# (or) Add serial numbers to all the levels
# df1.insert(0, ('serial_num_lv1', 'serial_num_lv2', 'serial_num_lv3'), np.arange(len(df1)) + 1)

# Q2
df2 = df.copy()

# Insert Delta between D4 and D5
df2.insert(
        df2.columns.get_loc(('A', 'C2', 'D4')) + 1,
        ('A', 'C2', 'Delta'),
        df2[('A', 'C2', 'D4')] - df2[('A', 'C2', 'D3')]
    )

# Sort D2 in desc order (* Note: In this sample, the differences are all 1.)
df2 = df2.sort_values(('A', 'C2', 'Delta'), ascending=False)

# Add serial numbers to only the top level
df2.insert(0, 'serial_num', np.arange(len(df2)) + 1)

# (or) Add serial numbers to all the levels
# df2.insert(0, ('serial_num_lv1', 'serial_num_lv2', 'serial_num_lv3'), np.arange(len(df2)) + 1)
```